# C# target host name for SSL/TLS (HTTPS) is always empty

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, .net-core, https

I have created a C# Web Server and I have some problems with the SSL/TLS certificates.

For the setup I have changed my `/etc/hosts` file for that any request to `example.com` will direct
to `localhost`. After that I have created a TCP server which works quite as expected. For the
HTTPS I added a `System.Net.Security.SslStream` layer with a default self-signed certificate which
also works as expected.

But for now I want to send a certificate that depends on the location the user requests. My server
code is like this:

```cs
var stream = new SslStream(
    innerStream: client.GetStream(), 
    leaveInnerStreamOpen: false, 
    userCertificateValidationCallback: null, 
    userCertificateSelectionCallback: LocalCertificateSelection
);
stream.AuthenticateAsServer(
    // I am forced to provide a default certificate. null will throw an error
    serverCertificate:          Settings.Certificate, 
    clientCertificateRequired:  false, 
    enabledSslProtocols:        SslProtocols.None, 
    checkCertificateRevocation: true
);

private X509Certificate LocalCertificateSelection(
    object sender, 
    string targetHost, 
    X509CertificateCollection localCertificates, 
    X509Certificate remoteCertificate, 
    string[] acceptableIssuers
)
{
    // at this point: targetHost == null && acceptableIssuers.Length == 0
    return Settings.Certificate;
};
```

But if I open the page in Firefox or in curl the `targetHost` and `acceptableIssuers` from my
certificate selection callback are always empty.

How am I supposed to get the host name to provide the correct certificate?

**Edit 1:**

My library is targeted for .Net Standard 2.1. Maybe this will help.

**Edit 2:**

I have added the certificate to the key store of the server (as it was mentioned in a comment), but this wont resolve the problem:

```cs
using var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.Add(Settings.Certificate);
```

After that I have captured some packages with Wireshark and I have noticed the following:

1. After TCP connection is finished:
2. Client sends a TLS Hello request with a valid SNI extension (here is the host name I want to get)
3. Debugger break point in my code is called. The SslStream tries to get a valid certificate: `targetHost` and `acceptableIssuers` are empty.
4. Server sends the default certificate with possible invalid host name

Comment: What encryption mode is the certificate?  the version of Net has to support the encryption mode of the certificate.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: *But for now I want to send a certificate that depends on the location the user requests.*  How?  The TLS connection is negotiated before the HTTP request is sent so you can't base the certificate selection off the URL requested.

Comment: @jdweng The default certificate is working. But for your interest: Its a RSA certificate with the subject set to `CN = example.com`. I can open the site in Firefox without a problem (except I have to allow untrused certificates).

@AndrewHenle I know the TLS connection is negotiated before HTTP but to allow multiple servers on one IP I have to use SNI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). That's the key here. With my understanding I have to provide a delegate like above to return the corresponding certificate for the name from the SNI. Here is the problem.

Comment: The certificate has to be loaded on client and server.  And the certificate has to be loaded in both the user and machine certificate stores.  When a client connects to a server using TLS the server send a certificate block with a list of certificate names that can be used.  Then the client looks up the names in the stores for a matching certificate.

Comment: @jdweng I have captured some requests to different HTTPS pages with Wireshark. None of them replicate the behavior you have described. At one point the client is sending (either in the first request or in the next message the client sends to the server) the SNI extension header with the server name and then the server sends a certificate. I have never seen a case where the server sends a list of certificate names.

Comment: In sniffer if you open the TLS messages from server to client one will contain the list of certificates.  As you said the TLS occurs before the Request and the Request will not be sent if the TLS fails.  The certificate is not sent.  Instead the certificate is installed on both client and server.  TLS just send the names of the certificates.